# How to make the buttons horizontal full width

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create three buttons horizontal and equal in size.
But what I managed to do so far is three buttons full width vertically as shown below.

```
<section class="section">
<div class="container-fluid">
...
<h2 class="display-5">User Management</h2>
   <br>
   <br>
   <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" role="button" href="{{ url_for('create_user') }}">Create New User</a>
   <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" role="button" href="{{ url_for('deactivate_user') }}">Deactivate user</a>
   <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" role="button" href="{{ url_for('change_user_password') }}">Change User Password</a>
...
</div>
```

and the output is:
[image]

How can I make them horizontal and taking the full width?

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I am using BS4.5.0

Comment: You mean you want to place buttons side by side and these buttons to occupy all 12 cols ?

Comment: @Akhil yes exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap comes with a very powerful Grid system that you can use, utilizing the classes `row` (for rows) and `col` (for columns) respectively.

The `col` class utilizes a number system of 1-12, indicating the size of the column in width. One entire row holds a max possible value of 12. How you choose your layout is entirely up to you. You can even nest the `row` and `col` classes as you wish to get the grid that you desire. More about Bootstrap Grid [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

**Example:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" role="button" href="{{ url_for('create_user') }}">Create New User</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4">
        <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" role="button" href="{{ url_for('deactivate_user') }}">Deactivate user</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4">
        <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" role="button" href="{{ url_for('change_user_password') }}">Change User Password</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Code snippet example:**

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" role="button" href="{{ url_for('create_user') }}">Create New User</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4">
        <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" role="button" href="{{ url_for('deactivate_user') }}">Deactivate user</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4">
        <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" role="button" href="{{ url_for('change_user_password') }}">Change User Password</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them inside a div, you can remove the btn-block and add col class to take columns automatically, something like below :

```
<div class="row">
    <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg col" role="button" href="{{ url_for('create_user') }}">Create New User</a>
    <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg col" role="button" href="{{ url_for('deactivate_user') }}">Deactivate user</a>
    <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg col" role="button" href="{{ url_for('change_user_password') }}">Change User
        Password</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It did the trick but there were no spacing between them. They looked as if they were one big button.

Comment: I thought that's how you wanted. You can add px-1 or mx-1 class with col to give padding/margin